# org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non-threadsafe access to the session Quarkus 3.2.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, quarkus

Good afternoon, I am currently working with quarkus 3.2.0 and I am having problems consuming a DB object of type SYS_REFCURSO, up to version 2.6 of quarkus I could obtain the data without problems, however, in this case I am having the following when trying return list from DB:

```
08-07-2023 11:12:29 ERROR [or.hi.AssertionFailure] (executor-thread-1) HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non-threadsafe access to the session
08-07-2023 11:12:29 ERROR [io.qu.ve.ht.ru.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-1) HTTP Request to /api/v2/FindPostpaidAccountByDocument failed, error id: a8eae0c4-5347-4d11-bd08-df8d2f860a76-1: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non-threadsafe access to the session                                                 
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:107)                                                                             
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:344)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:205)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:452)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:240)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:154)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:321)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:82)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:147)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:93)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non-threadsafe access to the session
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPostLoadEventListener.onPostLoad(DefaultPostLoadEventListener.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesSourceProcessingStateStandardImpl.lambda$postLoad$0(JdbcValuesSourceProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:183)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesSourceProcessingStateStandardImpl.postLoad(JdbcValuesSourceProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesSourceProcessingStateStandardImpl.finishUp(JdbcValuesSourceProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:165)
        at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.extractResults(OutputsImpl.java:251)
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.access$000(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:31)
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl$ProcedureCurrentReturnState.lambda$buildExtendedReturn$0(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.result.internal.ResultSetOutputImpl.getResultList(ResultSetOutputImpl.java:37)
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getResultList(ProcedureCallImpl.java:978)
        at com.tmve.account.repositoty.impl.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentRepository.getPostpaidAccount(FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentRepository.java:32)
        at com.tmve.account.service.impl.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentService.getPostpaidAccountListByDocument(FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentService.java:42)
        at com.tmve.account.service.impl.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentService_ClientProxy.getPostpaidAccountListByDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.tmve.account.controller.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentController.getPostpaidAccountListByDocument(FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentController.java:46)
        at com.tmve.account.controller.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentController_Subclass.getPostpaidAccountListByDocument$$superforward(Unknown Source)
        at com.tmve.account.controller.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentController_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.QuarkusRestPathTemplateInterceptor.restMethodInvoke(QuarkusRestPathTemplateInterceptor.java:39)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.QuarkusRestPathTemplateInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:30)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:27)
        at com.tmve.account.controller.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentController_Subclass.getPostpaidAccountListByDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.tmve.account.controller.FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentController_ClientProxy.getPostpaidAccountListByDocument(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:154)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:118)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:560)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:452)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:413)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:321)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:378)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:356)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:70)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:429)
        ... 15 more
```

My entity class

```
ackage com.tmve.account.beans;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.sql.Date;

@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                name = PostpaidAccount.NAME_QUERY_BUSCAR_CUENTAS_ROLES_X_DOC_IDE,
                procedureName = "PERS.PKG_COMP_CUENTAS.BUSCAR_CUENTAS_ROLES_X_DOC_ID",
                resultClasses = {PostpaidAccount.class},
                parameters = {
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Integer.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type = void.class),
                })
})
@Getter
@Entity
@ToString
public class PostpaidAccount {

    public static final String NAME_QUERY_BUSCAR_CUENTAS_ROLES_X_DOC_IDE=  "BuscarCuentasRolesxDocId";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5853819176277617472L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "V_NUMERO_CUENTA")
    Long account;
    @Column(name = "V_NUM_CTA_PAGADORA")
    Long billingAccountNumber;
    @Column(name = "V_NUM_CTA_DIG_VERI")
    Long billingAccountNumberValidators;
    @Column(name = "V_TIPO_CUENTA")
    String accountType;
    @Column(name = "V_ESTADO")
    String accountStatus;
    @Column(name = "V_NOMBRE_ESTADO")
    String accountStatusDescription;
    @Column(name = "V_ID_PRODUCTO")
    int productoId;
    @Column(name = "NOMBRE_PRODUCTO")
    String productName;
    @Column(name = "FECHA_INICIO_PROD")
    Date customerSince;
    @Column(name = "V_TITULAR_CUENTA")
    String accountHolder;
    @Column(name = "V_TIPO_RELACION")
    String relationshipType;
    @Column(name = "V_PLATAF")
    int platformId;
    @Column(name = "V_IDENTIFICADOR")
    String identifier;
    @Column(name = "NOMBRE_AREA")
    String marketName;
}
```

My Repository

```
package com.tmve.account.repositoty.impl;

import com.tmve.account.beans.PostpaidAccount;
import com.tmve.account.repositoty.IFindPostpaidAccountByDocumentRepository;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;


import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@Singleton
public class FindPostpaidAccountByDocumentRepository implements IFindPostpaidAccountByDocumentRepository {

    @Inject
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<PostpaidAccount> getPostpaidAccount(String documentType, String documentNumber) {

        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery=entityManager
                .createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("BuscarCuentasRolesxDocId");
        storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(1,documentNumber);
        storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(2,Integer.parseInt(documentType));

        storedProcedureQuery.execute();

        return (List<PostpaidAccount>) storedProcedureQuery.getResultList();
    }
}
```

When it is going to return the list, it is that it gives the hibernate exception described

My properties

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=oracle
#quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.jdbc.OpenTelemetryDriver
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=${URL_CONNECTION_BD:jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxx:xxxxxx/PERSDES}
quarkus.datasource.username=${USERNAME_CONNECTION_BD:APP_MS_PERS_DEV}
quarkus.datasource.password=${PASSWORD_CONNECTION_BD:xxxxxxxxx}
quarkus.http.port=${PORT:8080}
quarkus.http.ssl-port=${PORT-SSl:8082}
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect

quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=false
quarkus.hibernate-orm.jdbc.timezone=${TIME_ZONE_JDBC:GMT-4}
quarkus.hibernate-orm.validate-in-dev-mode = false

quarkus.log.level=INFO
quarkus.log.category."org.hibernate".level=INFO
# Send output to a trace.log file under the /tmp directory
quarkus.log.file.path=/tmp/trace.log
quarkus.log.console.format=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n
# Configure a named handler that logs to console
quarkus.log.handler.console."STRUCTURED_LOGGING".format=%e%n
# Configure a named handler that logs to file
quarkus.log.handler.file."STRUCTURED_LOGGING_FILE".enable=true
quarkus.log.handler.file."STRUCTURED_LOGGING_FILE".format=%e%n
# Configure the category and link the two named handlers to it
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.category".level=INFO
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.category".handlers=STRUCTURED_LOGGING,STRUCTURED_LOGGING_FILE

quarkus.application.name=FindPostpaidAccountByDocument
quarkus.opentelemetry.enabled=true
quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.exporter.otlp.endpoint=${URL_JAEGER:http://172.28.2.107:4317}

# Parametros para el certificado SSL
quarkus.ssl.native=true
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file=${UBICATION_CERTIFICATE_SSL:META-INF/resources/srvdevrma1.jks}
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file-type=${TYPE_CERTIFICATE_SSL:JKS}
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-password=${PASSWORD_CERTIFICATE_SSL:xxxxxxxxxx}
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-key-alias=${ALIAS_CERTIFICATE_SSL:srvdevrma1}
quarkus.native.add-all-charsets=true
quarkus.http.insecure-requests=disabled
quarkus.http.cors=true
quarkus.jackson.timezone=${TIME_ZONE:GMT-4}

quarkus.swagger-ui.path=/api/v2/FindPostpaidAccountByDocument/swagger-ui/
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.path=/api/v2/FindPostpaidAccountByDocument/swagger
quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true

quarkus.smallrye-openapi.info-title=FindPostpaidAccountByDocument
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.info-version=1.0.1
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.info-description=Microservicio que consulta todas las cuentas (USO y PAGADORA) asociado a un cliente pospago mediante su Documento Identidad
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.info-contact-email=gsgci.requerimientos@telefonica.com
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.info-contact-name=Middleware TI
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.tmve.account</groupId>
  <artifactId>find-postpaid-account-by-document-v2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>3.2.0.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.26</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-opentelemetry</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jacoco</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-oracle</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

This is how the Stored Procedure is displayed in BD:

```
DECLARE
  V_NUMERO_DOC VARCHAR2(20);
  V_TIPO_DOC NUMBER;
  V_LISTA SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  V_NUMERO_DOC := '000000';
  V_TIPO_DOC := 1;

  PKG_COMP_CUENTAS.BUSCAR_CUENTAS_ROLES_X_DOC_ID(
    V_NUMERO_DOC => V_NUMERO_DOC,
    V_TIPO_DOC => V_TIPO_DOC,
    V_LISTA => V_LISTA
  );
```

What could be happening, am I missing something in particular?

In version of Quarkus prior to version 3.0 work with javax and hibernate without problem with this type of object

Comment: Have you read the migration guide for Hibernate 6.x?

Comment: With the new version of Quarkus that works with jakarte, is there any change in Hibernate, what consideration should I take?

Comment: There are a lot of changes that have gone into Hibernate 6 (included with Quarkus 3). See https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-3.0#jpa-hibernate-orm